# Discord.JS Reaction Roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I don't know why my reaction role code won't work. If anyone could help me that would be appreciated!

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, person) => {
    if (reaction.partial) {
        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Something went wrong when fetching the message: ', error);
            return;
        };
    };

    if (reaction.emoji.name == ':tools:') {
        if (reaction.message.id === '769855387394375681')
        var server = client.guilds.cache.get('769100711593771038');
        let personMember = server.members.cache.get(person);
        const devRole = server.roles.cache.get('769428024609079319')
        personMember.roles.add(devRole);
    };

});

client.on('message', message => {
    return; //For now, gotta code more stuff later
});
```

The message function is there to cache the messages so that the bot can detect reactions on that message, Idk if it's really needed though.

There's also no errors, it just won't give me the role.

Comment: First of all, emoji names do not include the colons on both sides. It should just be `tools`. Second of all, it looks like you should combine your two `if` statements: `if (reaction.emoji.name == 'tools' && reaction.message.id === '769855387394375681') {`. If you're already comparing by ID, you don't need to compare by name as well, but either way works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an emoji ID, rather than just `:tools:` in your if statement. You can get this by typing the emoji in Discord, then putting a backslash in front of it. Send the message and you will get something like `<:tools:213812938712938713>`. The numerical part is your ID.

EDIT: You will need to do `if (reaction.emoji.id === 'IDHERE')`